# Simple Rock Paper Scissors in Erlang

Tags: rock-paper-scissors, erlang

I'm very new to Erlang and I'm specifically interested in making my Erlang idiomatic (in other words, can you tell I don't know Erlang from this code?) and removing code duplication. I am not as interested in performance or the UI of the "game."

This is a simple interactive Rock, Paper, Scissors game and I've been using `erlc rps.erl && ./rps-main.erl` to run it.

## rps.erl

```
-module(rps).
-export([play_game/1, get_random_symbol/0]).

get_symbol(1) -> rock;
get_symbol(2) -> paper;
get_symbol(3) -> scissors.

get_random_symbol() ->
    get_symbol(rand:uniform(3)).

play_game(InputFunctions) ->
    Score = [{win, 0}, {loss, 0}, {tie, 0}],
    play_game(Score, InputFunctions).

play_game(ok, _) ->
    ok;
play_game(Score, {Player1Input, Player2Input}) ->
    display_score(Score),
    Input1 = Player1Input(),
    Continue = Input1 =/= quit,
    Input2 = Player2Input(Continue),
    NewScore = compare_results(Input1, Input2, Score),
    play_game(NewScore, {Player1Input, Player2Input}).

compare_results(quit, _, _) ->
    ok;
compare_results(_, quit, _) ->
    ok;
compare_results(Same, Same, [Wins, Losses, {tie, Ties}]) ->
    [Wins, Losses, {tie, Ties+1}];
compare_results(rock, paper, [Wins, {loss, Losses}, Ties]) ->
    [Wins, {loss, Losses+1}, Ties];
compare_results(paper, scissors, [Wins, {loss, Losses}, Ties]) ->
    [Wins, {loss, Losses+1}, Ties];
compare_results(scissors, rock, [Wins, {loss, Losses}, Ties]) ->
    [Wins, {loss, Losses+1}, Ties];
compare_results(rock, scissors, [{win, Wins}, Losses, Ties]) ->
    [{win, Wins+1}, Losses, Ties];
compare_results(scissors, paper, [{win, Wins}, Losses, Ties]) ->
    [{win, Wins+1}, Losses, Ties];
compare_results(paper, rock, [{win, Wins}, Losses, Ties]) ->
    [{win, Wins+1}, Losses, Ties].

display_score([{win, Wins}, {loss, Losses}, {tie, Ties}]) ->
    io:format("Player1 Wins: ~B~nPlayer2 Wins: ~B~nTies: ~B~n", [Wins, Losses, Ties]).
```

## rpsgame.erl

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-
%%! -pa 'ebin/'
-import(rps, [play_game/1, get_random_symbol/0]).

main(_) -> 
    GetPlayerInput = fun() ->
        io:format("Enter rock, paper, scissors, or quit~n"),
        case io:get_line("> ") of
            "rock\n" -> rock;
            "paper\n" -> paper;
            "scissors\n" -> scissors;
            _ -> quit
        end
    end,
    GetCompInput = fun(Continue) when Continue =:= false ->
                        ok;
                    (_) ->
                        Input = rps:get_random_symbol(),
                        io:format("Computer threw ~p~n", [Input]),
                        Input
                    end,
    play_game({GetPlayerInput, GetCompInput}).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In whole not bad, but something can be simplified.

1.
In short functions don't need to create separate variables, especially if it is just a wrapper over the call of inner function. So play game/1 from rps can be rewritten as:

```
play_game(InputFunctions) ->
  play_game([{win, 0}, {loss, 0}, {tie, 0}], InputFunctions).
```

2.
Behavior of function for get result from player2 must not depend on result first player. Together with hint from 1 and giving an alias to the name of argument get

```
play_game(Score, {Player1Input, Player2Input} = P) ->
  display_score(Score),
  case Player1Input() of
    quit -> ok;
    Input -> play_game(new_score(Input, Player2Input(), Score), P)
  end.
```

where Player2Input/0:

```
  GetCompInput = fun() ->
    Input = rps:get_random_symbol(),
    io:format("Computer threw ~p~n", [Input]),
    Input
                 end,
```

new_score in my opinion, better captures the essence of the function than compare_results. This also allow delete first clause in new_score(compare_results)/3.

3.
Usage the symbol ***-*** in the name of the module is not very convenient,
 because you must wrap the name in ' ' when call function. Better use _ as delimiter.

4.
Not should use guard,when can use pattern matching. Compare

```
fun(Continue) when Continue =:= false ->
```

and

```
fun(false) ->
```

5.
Do not create an anonymous argument for a single function clause, in this case it is just an excess parameter.

```
 main(_) ->
```

6.
Do not use the directive import since it can will only confuse. If you know 
C++, it is possible to draw an analogy with an indicate explicit namespace instead of using namespace.

In addition I did not delete lines

```
play_game(ok, _) ->
  ok;
```

and

```
new_score(_, quit, _) ->
  ok;
```

although when playing with the computer this function clause does not get called.